# How to use MySql and Entity Framework 4.1 code first

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, code-first

I am trying to use MySQL database in MVCMusicStore
http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/ instead of MSSQL.
I would like to learn Code first development with MySQL.
I had added these code to web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
       connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=MvcMusicStore; Uid=root; Pwd=;"
       providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
         invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"  
         description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"  
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>   
</system.data>
```

MySQL database is already created but tables are not created.
I have just added `Mysql.Data.MySQLClient.dll` reference to my project. 
And I have this kind of exception:

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.data:
>   Column 'InvariantName' is constrained to be unique.
>   Value 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is already present.
>   (C:\Users\Dauren\Downloads\MvcMusicStore-v3.0\MvcMusicStore-v3.0\MvcMusicStore-Completed\MvcMusicStore\web.config line 47)

Comment: Thank you for the question and answer.
Another question on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354116/net-mysql-connector-conflicting-dbproviderfactories

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 <DbProviderFactories>  
   <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />  
     <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"     description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />  
  </DbProviderFactories>
```

Comment: Now i have this kind of error: _Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions._

Comment: @Dauren, you should either add (or simply don't remove) the IncludeMetadataConvention, or use some other database initialization strategy (not DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges).

Comment: Thanks, Above worked for me. Just a note, I was using different version of MySql.Data assembly, so just changed the Version 6.3.6.0 to Version=6.4.4.0.