# The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, connector-net

I have an asp.net solution using entity framework 6 to mysql server.

now I have to work on that solution on a new machine,
but I have some problems:
1) when building the solution I get error: **"The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file".**

[image: error screenshot]

App.config:

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

2) when opening model.edmx file I get message:
  **"the entity mode designer is unable to display the file you requested".**

[image: error screenshot]

I have installed on the machine:

1) mysql connector/net 6.9.9
2) mysql for visual studio 1.2.6
3) mysql connector odbc 5.3.6.

what can I do?

Answer (score 29):

I followed most suggested solutions in the internet but for sorry all were failed. The problem occurs because visual studio lacks for MySql connector and I have solved it by installing mysql-connector-net-7.0.4 (https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/)

Comment: I am using VS 2015 with a greenfield MVC 5 app. I tried everything else but still couldn't view the edmx. This was the last thing I tried after days of on and off attempts to solve the issue. This did the trick. As soon as the msi completed the edmx graphical interface came to life. Thanks very much!

Comment: @iQalalwa what to do after installation? What steps should I take now?

Comment: @faisal everything must be fine after restart your visual studio. no more steps

Comment: I asked a related question here: [Why do I still need the MySQL Connector installed on the computer despite having the proper NuGet packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53543848/3258851)

Comment: Same here, the MySQL .NET Connector was not installed into the GAG. I used the MySQL Installer software, installed it from there, and boom the Model Designer in Visual Studio opened the file.

Answer (score 13):

It works for me with the following section in app.config:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory,MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Answer (score 8):

I didn't have any MySql connector installed ony my machine.
Fixed it by installing nuget: MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity

[image]

Comment: this package is not available now. I found Mysql.Data.Entities package with similar description

Answer (score 6):

The above solutions didn't work for me. However, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25075756/3893015), I was able to resolve this problem by removing version information under the `entityFramework` tag in my `Web.config` file:

```
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory
       type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
        </provider>
      </providers>
    </entityFramework>
```

becomes:

```
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory
       type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
        </provider>
      </providers>
    </entityFramework>
```

ETA: As pointed out in [this follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43193382/3893015) it may also be necessary to manually edit the version of `MySql.Data` in the `Web.config` file:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.9.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done lot of google and find the solution 
Ensure MySQL.Data.dll, MySQL.Web.dll, MySQL.Data.Entity.dll, and System.Data.Entity.dll are all being copied local (right click on assembly and ensure Copy Local is set to true)
I also added the following locally as I tried to debug this problem but it was probably unnecessary
System.Data.dll [probably optional]
System.Data.Entity.Design [probably optional]

And here's the step you wont read about in many places on google or on AppHarbor!
Add the following to your web.config file:

```
  <system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <clear />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
    type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, 
    Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve it by adding only the attribute "DbConfigurationType" to my context class, I found it in a codesample I had from somewhere, but can't recall the origin sorry. it is the same as Dmitry's answer but using an attribute instead as implementation

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MySqlWeatherContext : DbContext
{
    public MySqlWeatherContext() : base("context"){}

    public DbSet<Measurepoint> Measurepoints { get; set; }
}
```

This is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="context" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve this problem, in addition to the changes outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452900/the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name-mysql-data-mysqlclient-is-either-not/42309674#42309674), I also had to manually edit the version of `MySql.Data` in `web.config` like so:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.9.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Why does this not update automatically when you install v6.9.9?  This fixed my problem.  Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

You must add 
`codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"` to  in your configuration file or call `DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration())` at the application start up.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for **MySQL 8.0.29**.

Add bellow script to **App.config** of your project.

```
<configuration>
<system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
     <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
     <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.29, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
   </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>       
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the old reference of MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 from the list of references. Reinstall via Nuget Package manager and it will work/

Answer (score 0):

Add to your  web.config

```
<entityFramework>
 <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework" />
</providers>
```

Add the DbConfigurationType attribute in the current context class

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MeuContexto: DbContext { }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.10.msi and mysql-connector-net-8.0.25 uses same version. If you use mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.10.msi, you have to use this version of the connector: mysql-connector-net-8.0.25