# No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to do a LINQ query to my database. However, my `try catch` sentences catches an error.

I added an ADO.NET and it finds my server and tables fine, but when I try to query data from my `dbContext`, I get this error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  No Entity Framework provider
>   found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the
>   'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Can you show the EntityFramework section of your application config file? Then somebody can find and correct your problem.

Comment: it is already answered check link will help you :-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452900/the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name-mysql-data-mysqlclient-is-either-not