# EntityFramework Schema specified is not valid exception

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, entity-framework-6

When trying to run my code in production I get the following exception:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Schema specified is not valid. Errors: (0,0) : error 0175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerInvariantName, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer'2& cachedCTypeFunction) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.XDocumentExtensions.GetStorageMappingItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ModelMatches(VersionedModel model) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) at RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.Database.SQL.PSSContext..ctor() in E:\OneDrive\Projects\PSS\RAWCT.PSS.WebServices\RAWCT.PSS.WebServices\Database\SQL\PSSContext.cs:line 52 at RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.Controllers.AccountController.CreateAccount(Int32 payrollID, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, Boolean approved, Boolean jobLog, Boolean photoApp) in E:\OneDrive\Projects\PSS\RAWCT.PSS.WebServices\RAWCT.PSS.WebServices\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 35 at RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.Account.NewAccount(String payrollID, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String approved, String jobLog, String photoApp) in E:\OneDrive\Projects\PSS\RAWCT.PSS.WebServices\RAWCT.PSS.WebServices\Account.svc.cs:line 58 at SyncInvokeNewAccount(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

The thing is I am not using MySQL for this project at all only MSSQL so I am unsure where it is getting that I am? This works fine on the test server. Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.Account">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" name="AccountService" contract="RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.Interfaces.IAccount" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.JobLogs">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" name="JobLogsService" contract="RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.Interfaces.IJobLogs" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.JobSite">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" name="JobSiteService" contract="RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.Interfaces.IJobSite" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.TimeClock">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" name="TimeClockService" contract="RAWCT.PSS.WebServices.Interfaces.ITimeClock" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452900/the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name-mysql-data-mysqlclient-is-either-not)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as stated I am NOT using MySQL in anyway. Only attempting to use SQL. That post is regarding someone trying to use MySQL.

Comment: So why do you have `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` in there?

Comment: That was me attempting to remove any relation to it. It throws the same error with or without trying to remove it via web.config