# Why do I still need the MySQL Connector installed on the computer despite having the proper NuGet packages?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

I've got a C# ASP.NET MVC project using MariaDB with Entity Framework 6.

This project is made in Visual Studio 2017 and it took me some long hours double-checking whether I had the proper MySQL connector's assembly references added as they should, in the form of NuGet packages [MySql.Data 8.0.13](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) and [MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.13](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework/) (both oficially published by Oracle), because I was getting the following error when browsing Views while debugging:

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file.

Until I gave up on it and tried installing the [MySQL Connector/NET 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/8.0.html), after which it worked. No changes made to the `web.config` file other than those performed by NuGet.

I checked the assemblies placed under `%ProgramFiles%\MySql\Connector` by the installer, and they are bit-identical to those pulled by NuGet. Heck, **I even deleted the entire folder, and it still worked**.

What gives? Are the NuGet packages missing some step they should perform?

Comment: Why don't you try to contact the owners of those packages with your finding(s) on the nuget.org website so they can investigate and fix it?

Comment: @RaymondNijland that's actually a good suggestion, I'll follow it. Unfortunately these packages lack any description and the documentation in their website is missing this, so I was at a loss as to whether this was expected behavior or not.

Comment: "Unfortunately these packages lack any description and the documentation in their website is missing thi" i tend to **avoid** programming languages , library's or source code without descriptions and or good documentation of any kind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that the Connector/NET 8.0 installer modifies your `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config` file, which is shared by all .NET applications on the machine. Unfortunately, this is a local change on your machine, which means that your application may not work properly when deployed.

The solution is to add MySql.Data to your `app.config` (or `Web.config`) file. I'm not sure if the NuGet packages are designed to do this automatically or not.

Per [the Oracle docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html), add this information to `app.config`:

```
<system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
     <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
     <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" 
          type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
   </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: My app was running inside a Docker container and needed this to succeed. I didn't find this answer anywhere else, thanks!