# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider error on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mysql-connector

I'm using asp.net MVC with MySql database.
I have `MySql.Data v8.0.16.0`, `MySql.Data.EntityFramework v8.0.16.0` and `MySqlConnector v0.47.1.0` installed.

and in web.config connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=bakradb;Uid=root;Pwd=***;Allow User Variables=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

and provider:

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider>
```

The database connectivity is working fine on my local pc but when I deploy on hosting server it says:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not
>   be installed.

**Stack trace:**

```
[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +1044767
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup) +77

[ArgumentException: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.<GetService>b__0(ArgumentException e, String n) +49
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup) +97
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +81
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k) +26
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +140
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r) +19
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +58
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +161
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key) +160
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +66
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r) +19
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +58
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +94
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key) +160
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key) +65
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService(IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key) +84
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateConnectionFromProviderName(String providerInvariantName) +47
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +111
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +33
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +130
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_Connection() +89
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1.IsIdentityV1Schema(DbContext db) +52
   Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject.Helpers.CategoryHelper.GetCategories() in C:\Users\mirfa\source\Helpers\CategoryHelper.cs:19
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\vhosts\abc\httpdocs\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:17
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +73
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9874041
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

I have double checked dll version on hosting server and everything looks good, what could be the possible reason for this error?

All the database connectivity dependencies are includes with project and its not dependent on server. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [mysql .net connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/8.0.html) on server and it solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with the DbProviderFactories section in app.config

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory,MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Try the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543848/why-do-i-still-need-the-mysql-connector-installed-on-the-computer-despite-having)

Comment: I have tried this and it didn't worked because the variant name is already added.