# Entity Framework with mySQL VisualStudio 2019

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mysql-connector

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Entity Framework provider type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application.

This is my app.config file. I cant figure out why i get this error. I've been stuck for days with other posts not giving any help.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.18.0" newVersion="8.0.18.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EntityFramework">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StudentForYouEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/StudentForYouDataBase.csdl|res://*/StudentForYouDataBase.ssdl|res://*/StudentForYouDataBase.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=remotemysql.com;user id=dx01fvQECG;password=password;database=myDataBase;persistsecurityinfo=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: i found out that it is somehow related to app.config in another project(webapp) when you try to display provider 'System.Data.SqlClient' it throws this exception

Comment: what .Net framework version are you running on?

Comment: Have you made sure that the correct assembly-qualified name is being used and that the assembly is available to the running application?

Comment: How do i that? sorry new to this

Comment: @Deleted v4.7.2

Comment: Can you remove or comment out one of the Providers and vice versa. You have two I think you only need one.

Comment: @Deleted It didn't help, even if i delete both i get the same error. it doesn't even see the provider

Comment: @ Mantas Mantas - Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452900/the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name-mysql-data-mysqlclient-is-either-not) maybe it will be helpful, it looks like the invariant name does not match to what its install on your PC, also you might need mySQLConnectorNet.Entity

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your app can't load MySql.Data.EntityFramework Version=8.0.18.0, have you tried installing it via NuGet?

[image]

Comment: i have it installed