# Error loading assembly 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' when deploying ASP.net application to AWS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am getting the below exception message when I publish my Asp.NET application to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk intance.  The database is on Amazon RDS.  The application runs fine locally with a local MySql database.  I've tried many of the suggested answers on Stack Overflow but none have proven to work yet.  Has anybody had this issue when deploying a .NET application?

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6,
>   Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
>   registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider
>   with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make
>   sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is
>   available to the running application. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
>       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(String
>   providerTypeName, String providerInvariantName)
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__2(ProviderElement
>   e)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>
> at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>
> at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterDbProviderServices()
>
> at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type
>   type, String name)
>
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 predicate)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver
>   resolver)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection
>   internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
>
> at MichHerbAcumaticaApi.Models.ApplicationDbContext.Create()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   ar)
>
> at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

```
<packages>
  ......
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.9.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entity" version="6.9.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MySql.Web" version="6.9.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  .....
</packages>
```

I've tried the following solutions with no luck:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40574224/5481661

[Entity Framework Provider type could not be loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033193/entity-framework-provider-type-could-not-be-loaded/19130718#19130718)

[.NET MySQL Connector Conflicting DbProviderFactories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354116/net-mysql-connector-conflicting-dbproviderfactories)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have tried? Is the MySQL Connector/NET part of the deployment?

Comment: Does the connector need to be installed separately on the server or is it part of the Nuget packages for MySql?  I'm using v6.9.9 for the MySql packages.  I included the MySql part of my package.json above.

Comment: The connector is part of the MySql.Data NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have followed all the steps from the below mySQL documentation. As per the documentation it states that 
"Unless MySQL Connector/Net was installed with the standalone MSI or MySQL Installer, which adds the reference, insert the following data provider information into the app.config or web.config file:"
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have checked all of my setting to this documentation and it appears I have everything correct.  Still not working :(

Comment: Please check the below settings are applied. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.rds.html

Comment: I did have that setup (that's the instructions I used originally) but it wasn't working.  I ended up spinning up a new AWS instance and redeploying and it worked.  Not sure why? Maybe some configuration got screwed up on the last one